# Inserting Duplicate row in hive based on conditions

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, hiveql

I have a situation in which i am inserting data into a table, but in between if it face a condition such as case when a(<>B) I want to process the same row.

I want 2 entries of the same row in the new table. Is there any to insert same row again in hive.

Comment: please provide and example of desired input and output

Answer (score 0):

You can insert all rows once into the table, then issue another insert (without overwrite) only for rows that satisfy your condition.